# spotify not saving app

Tags: spotify

i have followed the hello world for spotify

it shows the name of the current playing song and album

but it doesnt show the `"hello world"` message

also,
whenever I close spotify, and open it again, my app dissapears, even though i have clicked on the

> Add Application to Favorites

"Add"  button

why does the app dissapear, after closing spotify?

and why is my hello world not showing,

i have just pasted the zipped file from the spotify tutorial in to my ~/Spotify
folder

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code, you'll see the "Hello World" message is removed during the tutorial.

Spotify doesn't save local apps in the sidebar across relaunches - only ones from the App Finder.